# Nodejs and swagger file upload : TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, swagger, swagger-ui

**EDIT**

I found what my mistakes were. 
I received a "TypeError: Failed to fetch" because I wasn't sending back anything in my controller function. So replacing  console.log("OK") by res.json({"message": "File Uploaded"}); fixed that. 
But, my image still wasn't getting uploaded and that's because I wasn't using __dirname in the path where I wanted the image to be stored. I set up __dirname in my app.js file.

---

I'm trying to upload a file in my server using express-fileupload npm package. When testing it with Swagger UI, I get the following error: "TypeError: Failed to fetch" and my file doesn't get uploaded in my public/images folder

Here is my swagger:

```
  /images:
    x-swagger-router-controller: images
    post:
      summary: Uploads a file.
      operationId: upload
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      parameters:
        - in: formData
          name: upfile
          type: file
          description: The file to upload.
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/SuccessResponse"
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
```

Here is my images controller:

```
function upload(req, res, next) {

  let uploadFile = req.files.upfile;
  let fileName = uploadFile.name;
  uploadFile.mv( `../../public/images/${fileName}`, function (err) {
         if (err) {
         console.log("error", err)
         }
         console.log("OK")
         })
}

   module.exports = {
    upload,
};
```

My "OK" message do get printed in my console though.

Does someone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Sounds like a CORS issue. What is the error message in the browser console?

Comment: So I get this : POST http://localhost:7672/api/images net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: Ok so I made a dumb mistake by just printing out ok when there was no error. I replaced console.log("OK") by res.json({  "message": "File Uploaded" }); and it worked. But my file still doesn't get uploaded.

Comment: What is the error message in the browser console on the Swagger UI page? (not in the Node.js console)

Comment: That's the only thing that was displayed in the browser console on the Swagger UI page. But I managed to fix my issue thanks to your comment. Thank you very much!

Comment: Consider posting your solution in the Answer section so that it can help future visitors.